# onselect input values in popup window store in parent window input fields?

Tags: mysql, ajax, jsp

```
<% String s1= request.getParameter("filter");%>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var imageURL = "redar.jpg";
            function changeImage(img_id)
            {
                var imgs=document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
                for(var i=1;i<=imgs.length;i++) {
                    var imgid="myImage"+i;
                    if(imgid==img_id){
                        document.getElementById(img_id).src="greenar.gif";
                    }
                    else{
                        document.getElementById(imgid).src=imageURL;
                    }
                }
            }
            function trim(stringToTrim) {
                return stringToTrim.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
            }
            function validate()
            {   
                var emp_value ="";
                var count=0;
                var imgs=document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
                for(var i=1;i<=imgs.length;i++) 
                {  var imgid="myImage"+i;
                    var imgurl = document.getElementById(imgid).src;
                    var imgar = imgurl.split("/");
                    if(imgar[4]=="greenar.gif")
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if(count==0)
                {
                    alert("Please Select Employee Id");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            function showEmp()
            {   if(validate())
                {   
                    var imgs=document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
                    for(var i=1;i<=imgs.length;i++) {
                        var imgid="myImage"+i;
                        var emp_id = "eid"+i;
                        var imgurl = document.getElementById(imgid).src;
                        var imgar = imgurl.split("/");
                        if(imgar[4]=="greenar.gif"){
                            var emp_value = document.getElementById(emp_id).value;
                        }
                    }
                    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
                    if (xmlHttp==null){
                        alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request")
                        return
                    }
                    var url="getPatient.jsp"
                    url=url+"?emp_id="+emp_value;
                    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged 
                    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
                    xmlHttp.send(null)
                }
            }
            function stateChanged() 
            {  if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
                {   var showdata = xmlHttp.responseText;
                    var strar = showdata.split(":");
                    if(strar.length>0)
                   {
                       var strname = strar[1];
                       window.opener.location.reload();
                        window.location.reload(); 
                        window.close(); 
                        opener.document.getElementById("puid").value=strar[1];
                        opener.document.getElementById("fname").value=strar[2];
                        opener.document.getElementById("prdate").value=strar[3];
                        window.close();
                    }
                } 
            }
            function GetXmlHttpObject()
            {   var xmlHttp=null;
                try
                {   // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
                    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                catch (e)
                {  //Internet Explorer
                    try
                    {
                        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch (e)
                    {
                        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                }
                return xmlHttp;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="employee">
            <br><br>
            <table border="1" width="300px" align="center" bgcolor="#CDFFFF">
                <tr><td align="center" colspan=3><b>Select Patient</b></td></tr>
                <%  System.out.println(s1);
                    Connection conn = null;
                    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
                    String dbName = "gold";
                    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                    String userName = "root";
                    String password = "root";
                    int sumcount = 0;
                    Statement st;
                    try {
                        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
                        String query = "select * from gold.newdailyupdate where pmobileno='" + s1 + "' ";
                        st = conn.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                        int count = 0;
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            count++;
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="hidden" value="<%=rs.getString(20)%>" id="eid<%=count%>"></td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <img src="redar.jpg" width="25px" height="25px" name="myImage" onclick="changeImage(this.id);" id="myImage<%=count%>" border="0"></td>
                    <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
                    <td width="50%"><%=rs.getString(20)%></td>
                </tr>
                <%
                    }
                %>
                <%  } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                %>
                <tr><td align="center" Colspan=3><input type="button" value="Select" onclick="javascript:showEmp();"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my popup window page , where i can select the values in popup window, those values must be populated to parent window fields .
I am not able to store the values in parent window fields , but " undefined " value is storing in all the fields in parent window , i am unable to find the error.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)  Can you not narrow down the problem in order to arrive at a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: when i enter id in parent window form i should popup window with list those who r registered with same id, so when i select particular user in popup those vales must be stored in fields in parent window . i am storing undiefined value in all the fields .

Comment: var strname = strar[1];
                       window.opener.location.reload();
                        window.location.reload(); 
                        window.close(); 
                        opener.document.getElementById("puid").value=strar[1];
                        opener.document.getElementById("fname").value=strar[2];
                        opener.document.getElementById("prdate").value=strar[3];
       here i am not able to get the values ....

Comment: Can you try replacing those lines with `alert(strar[1]);` etc to see whether the array contains what you expect?  If it doesn't, then you might want to try `alert(xmlHttp.responseText);` to see what the XHR is actually returning.

Comment: var showdata = xmlHttp.responseText; 
                  alert(showdata)                                                                      i added this here i am displaying empty alert. how to get out of this .

Comment: And in `showEmp()`, could you `alert(url);` just before the call to `xmlHttp.open()`?  Then try opening that `url` in your browser directly to see what is returned by the server.

Comment: by alert(url) i got this getPatient.jsp?emp_id=P00001/

Comment: And if you load that URL in your browser...?

Comment: var showdata = xmlHttp.responseBody;
                  alert(showdata)  when i replace responseText with responseBody , it is displaying undefined in alert

Comment: wats wrong i did in this , any one there